# Put method replacing the previous object of the jsonarray

Tags: android, json

I was trying to form this type of `jsonarray`.

```
[
 { 
  "userIdentity":"bbb",
  "admin":true/false
 },
 { 
  "userIdentity":"bbb",
  "admin":true/false
 }
.
.
.

        ]
```

I used this code in android giving input from a `hashmap` toAdd:

```
        JSONObject inerobj=new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray();
        for (String s : toAdd.keySet()) {
        //  Log.d("userid",s);
          inerobj.put("userIdentity", s);
          inerobj.put("admin", Boolean.parseBoolean(toAdd.get(s)));
          Log.d("inerobj.toString",inerobj.toString());
          jsonarray.put(inerobj);
          Log.d("jsonarray.toString",jsonarray.toString());             
        }
```

the hashmap toAdd has:

```
towhid37:value=true
towhid32:value=true
```

in `inerobj` the value is ok.But when appending the `inerobj` to jsonarray, it adds 1st `value(towhid37)` ok. bt when it puts 2nd `value(towhid32)` it replaces 1st value also ie 1st element of the array now becomes (towhid32).

Heres Logcat output:

```
05-20 12:20:43.968: D/inerobj.toString(3788): {"admin":true,"userIdentity":"towhid37"}

05-20 12:20:43.988: D/jsonarray.toString(3788): [{"admin":true,"userIdentity":"towhid37"}]

05-20 12:20:43.988: D/inerobj.toString(3788): {"admin":true,"userIdentity":"towhid32"}

05-20 12:20:44.038: D/jsonarray.toString(3788): [{"admin":true,"userIdentity":"towhid32"},{"admin":true,"userIdentity":"towhid32"}]
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
inerobj=new JSONObject();
```

inside the for loop.

From what I understand, it stores the reference to the JSONObject instead of its values, that is why the values seems to be overwritten. Just re-initialize the variable to add new values.